# react router v6 searchParams has old value in callback

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Search Params values does not change after navigating to the same url with different query params.

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams()
const checkConfirm = useCallback(() => {
    const confirmedWindowApi = window.location.href.includes('confirmed=1') // OK
    const confirmedSearchParams = searchParams.get('confirmed') == '1' // Wrong(still 0)
}, [searchParams])
```

Some where I run this:

```
navigate(location.pathname + '?confirmed=1', {replace: true})
```

But search params doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead using the `setSearchParams` function it issue the redirect.

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
const checkConfirm = useCallback(() => {
  const confirmedSearchParams = searchParams.get('confirmed') === '1';
}, [searchParams]);

...

searchParams.set("confirmed", "1");
setSearchParams(searchParams, { replace: true });
```

Or extract the `confirmed` queryString parameter outside the callback and use *that* as the dependency.

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
const confirmed = searchParams.get('confirmed');

const checkConfirm = useCallback(() => {
  const confirmedSearchParams = confirmed === '1';
}, [confirmed]);

...

searchParams.set("confirmed", "1");
setSearchParams(searchParams, { replace: true });
```